# Oracle SQL Statement LONG Not Retrieved From DB

Tags: .net, sql, oracle

I am accessing an Oracle database from a .NET application.  The structure of my code is as follows:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Oradb))
{
  conn.Open();

  string sql = "SELECT RI_DESCRIPTION 
                  FROM RI_RISK 
                 WHERE RI_CODE = 'GAIL'";
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

  OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  dr.Read();

  var result = dr.GetString(0);

  Assert.AreEqual("Golden Arches Insurance", result);
}
```

Now, I cannot get this statement to return anything - assert fails, result = "";

But, I can get this statement to return what is expected:

```
string sql = "SELECT CLI_ABBRNAME 
                FROM CLI_CLIENT 
               WHERE CLI_CLIENTNUMBER = 00404";
```

I have checked a number of times that the table and column names are correct.  The only difference I can see is the data types:

- RI_DESCRIPTION is LONG
- RI_CODE is VARCHAR2
- CLI_CLIENTNUMBER is VARCHAR2
- CLI_ABBRNAME is VARHCHAR2

Therefore, is there something I have to do with a LONG that I'm not doing in the code?

Also, CLI_CLIENTNUMBER is really a VARCHAR2, why don't I need single apostrophes around 00404 in the statement, whereas for RI_CODE which is VARCHAR2 I do (apparently) need apostrophes around 'GAIL' (otherwise I get an Invalid Identifier exception?

** EDIT

The statement works perfectly well on SQL Plus

** EDIT - SOLUTION

The trick, following the link in the answer, was to set the OracleCommand object InitialLONGGetchSize to -1.

Comment: The DB appears to be a mess: A description shouldn't be a number (LONG), and a number (LONG) can't be "Golden Arches Insurance".

Comment: run the sql directly against the database (not from your application) - verify that you get the expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One, you should not be using LONG. You should convert this field to a CLOB. LONGs are deprecated.

If you are using ODP.NET, I found this on ["Obtaining LONG and LONG RAW Data"](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featData.htm#i1007197). It looks like a parameter, `InitialLONGFetchSize`, is intially set to 0 and you need to increase it to retrieve LONGs.

And, well, technically you do need the quotes, but since you're comparing your column against a number, I think there is an implicit conversion. What you're doing is equivalent to:

```
SELECT CLI_ABBRNAME 
  FROM CLI_CLIENT 
 WHERE TO_NUMBER(CLI_CLIENTNUMBER) = 404
```